# Getting value from dropdownlist in jsp to spring mvc controller using hibernate annottations

Tags: mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, hibernate-annotations

Hi  I am writing a program using spring mvc hibernate and mysql as database.I have two tables **employee** and **team** in mysql db.I am using jsp as my view.In my jsp i am loading team names from team table to a dropdownlist.I want  to display all employees in specefic team when i select the specefic team from the dropdown list and click the submitt buttton

Here is my jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
      <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form:form method="POST" action="Search.html" modelAttribute="command">

  <table>
    <tr>
                    <form:label path="teams.teamId">Team Name</form:label>

                    <td>
                        <form:select path="teams.teamId" cssStyle="width: 150px;">    
                            <option value="-1">Select a type</option>
                            <c:forEach items="${teamKey}" var="teams">
                            <option value="${teams.teamId}">${teams.teamName}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </form:select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

    <tr>



    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"  value="submit">  </td>

    </tr>



  </table>

 </form:form>
 <h1><a href="retunTohome.html">Home</a></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

my jsp view

[image]

controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Search",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView fromSearch(@ModelAttribute("command") Resource resource,BindingResult result){
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/searchResult.html");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/searchResult",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getValue(@ModelAttribute("command") Resource resource ,Model m){


    m.addAttribute("command", "Got value here"+resource.toString());
    return "Search";
}
```

Resource class

```
   @Entity
        @Table(name="Employee")
        public class Resource implements Serializable {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -723583058586873479L;   


            @Id
            @Column(name="empid")
            private Integer empId;

            @Column(name="empname")
            private String empName;

            @Column(name="empexp")
            private Integer empExp;


            @Column(name="empskills")
            private String empSkills;



             @ManyToOne
             @JoinColumn(name="teamId",referencedColumnName="teamId")
             private AddTeam teams;



            public Integer getEmpId(){
                return empId;
            }
            public void setEmpId(Integer empId){
                this.empId=empId;
            }


            public String getEmpName(){
                return empName;
            }
            public void setEmpName(String empName){
                this.empName=empName;
            }

            public Integer getEmpExp(){
                return empExp;
            }
            public void setEmpExp(Integer empExp){
                this.empExp=empExp;
            }


            public String getEmpSkills(){
                return empSkills;
            }
            public void setEmpSkills(String empSkills){
                this.empSkills=empSkills;
            }



            public AddTeam getTeams() {
                  return teams;
                 }

                 public void setTeams(AddTeam teams) {
                  this.teams = teams;
                 }

        }


AddTeam.class

    @Entity
@Table(name="Team")

public class AddTeam {


    @Id
    @Column(name="teamId")
    private Integer teamId;

    @Column(name="teamName")
    private String teamName;

    public Integer getTeamId() {
          return teamId;
         }

         public void setTeamId(Integer teamId) {
          this.teamId = teamId;
         }

         public String getTeamName() {
          return teamName;
         }

         public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
          this.teamName = teamName;
         }

     }
```

ResourceDao Impl class

```
@Override
    public void serchResources(int teamid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(" FROM Resource WHERE teamId=" +teamid);


    }
```

Error

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'teams' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'teams' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:665)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:518)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:495)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:655)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:147)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.Search_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(Search_jsp.java:306)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.Search_jsp._jspService(Search_jsp.java:117)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I am new to spring hibernate application , i am stuck here.Is there any method to display the selected teams employee...

Thanks for any advice...

Comment: what is AddTeam ? Are you extending the example from this http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/spring-mvc-hibernate-maven-crud-operations-example.html

Comment: You only showed the GET part of the controller, and the error seems to be in the POST part ... Please show it too.

Comment: @SanKrish thank u for looking into the issue. AddTeam is a class which handles another jsp addTeam.jsp which provides the functionalty for addind and deleting teams

Comment: @SergeBallesta thank u for looking into the issue i had added the POST part.Please look onto my edited code

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be hard to maintain :

- you call `Resource` what could be called `Employee` class (table name is `Employee`)
- you call `AddTeam` what could be called `Team` class (table name is `Team`)
- you call `teams` (plural) a single `AddTeam` element
- you use a full `Resource` object to simply get a team
- all that without a comment

I suppose you just want to get a team in that jsp, and the form sends correctly a teamId. It can work that way, thanks to spring magic, but you need to declare a `Converter<String, AddTeam>` to convert the String sent by browser (representation of the teamId) to the AddTeam having that id.

To have it integrating prorperly in spring you must :

- declare a `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean` bean (if you don't, you will loose all default conversions)
- declare a `Converter<String, AddTeam>` bean for the conversion String -> Integer -> AddTeam and register it into the above ConversionService

And in your form, the path for the select should only be `teams` :

```
<form:select path="teams" ...
```

It is a rather advanced config, but it can work.

---

If you prefere something less magic, use a true form (not a model object) :

```
class TeamCommand {
    private int teamId;
    // getter and setter ommitted for bievety
}
```

In your controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Search",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView fromSearch(@ModelAttribute("command") TeamCommand command,BindingResult result){
    AddTeam team = service.method(command.getTeamId);
    ...
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/searchResult.html");
}
```

In your JSP :

```
<form:select path="teamId" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some changes that may solve your problem,

in jsp file

**Current**

```
<form:select path="teams.teamId" cssStyle="width: 150px;">
```

**Have to change**

```
<form:select path="teams" cssStyle="width: 150px;">
```

**In your controller class**

**Current**

```
public String getValue(@ModelAttribute("command") Resource resource ,Model m)
```

**Have to change**

```
public String getValue(@ModelAttribute("command") Resource resource ,Model m,
 @RequestParam("teams") String teamId)
```

and **add below code in your controller class**

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

    binder.registerCustomEditor(AddTeam.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {

        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) {
            AddTeam teams = new AddTeam();
            teams.setTeamId(Integer.valueOf(text));
            this.setValue(teams);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem. :)